# InteliJ IDEA desktop entry Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

My start menu shortcut of the JetBrains InteliJ IDEA 15 IDE is no longer working on my Linux Mint 17.3 x64. When I try to use it nothing happens. I tried to delete the shortcut and to use the Create Desktop Entry function of the program but it didn't work, and I also tried to recreate the shortcut manually. I can only start the application by using: `sudo sh install_path/bin/idea.sh' in the terminal. My shortcut code is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Icon=/usr/local/InteliJ_IDEA/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin/idea.png
Exec="/usr/local/JetBrains/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin/idea.sh" %f  
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

How can I make my shortcut work again?

Comment: To help troubleshoot, what is the output when you run `ls -lh /usr/local/JetBrains/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin/idea.sh`, and what are the contents of `/usr/local/JetBrains/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin/idea.sh`? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=15.0.2
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/opt/idea-IU-143.1184.17/bin/idea.png
Name[en_US]=IntelliJ
Exec=/opt/idea-IU-143.1184.17/bin/idea.sh
Name=IntelliJ
Icon=/opt/idea-IU-143.1184.17/bin/idea.png
```

with the mod permissions:

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/applications/intellij.desktop
sudo chown root:root /usr/share/applications/intellij.desktop
```

Referenced from [here](https://gist.github.com/rob-murray/6828864)